# Can I make ansible no_log default based on ansible verbosity level?

Tags: ansible

There are lots of ansible modules which have very verbose output by default, like `sync`, `file`, and all `os_*` ones, which had the bad habit of returning huge results on console.

`ANSIBLE_VERBOSITY` level is useless for these because even level 0 does not remove "results" from the output.

Using alternative output plugins via `ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK` is another lost cause because at this moment none of the existing alternative callbacks had an option to disable these.

Adding `no_log: true` or smarter alternatives like `no_log: result.rc == 0` to each occurrence of spammy module does not scale in practice.

I know that can define `no_log: true` at playbook level, but this does not allow me to enable logging conditionally.

Answer (score 3):

If you want 'clean' solution, you should definitely write a custom callback plugin to reduce amount of output to required level.

But you have an option to use this workaround to conditionally template `no_log` based on verbosity:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  no_log: "{{ verbose_check | default(dict(skipped=true)) | skipped }}"
  vars:
    mydict:
      password: abc
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "Shown only with verbosity > 2"
        verbosity: 3
      register: verbose_check

    - debug:
        var: mydict
```

`debug` module has built-in ability to be skipped depending on verbosity level. We can register it's output and define `no_log` based on it. And because of the fact that Jinja `{{...}}` expressions are templated when used and not when defined, every following task will evaluate `no_log` to `true` or `false` depending on skipped state our `verbose_check`.

Answer (score 2):

You can template the `no_log` option based on the verbosity level (which is exposed in `ansible_verbosity`, at least as of 2.9)

This will supress it for one of the tasks, unless the verbosity is 3 or higher.

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: Show verbosity level
    debug:
      var: ansible_verbosity
  - name: Get a list of installed packages
    no_log: "{{ ansible_verbosity < 3 }}"
    package_facts:
      manager: auto
```

(This should also work play-wide, by combining this with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48590023/1837991))